# Jquery document.referrer control

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this question.

I have a jquery function running on an if/else statement based on the document.referrer. Note that this is Jquery formatted for WordPress usage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
var lastUrl = document.referrer;
  if(lastUrl.indexOf("blog/") > -1 ){
//the first action
}
else {
//the second action
}
});
});
```

So if the user came from a blog post, I initiate the first action otherwise I initiate the second one.

This works fine if the user comes to the page containing this function from a blog post (url example ".com/blog/blog-post") however if the user clicks on the blog menu item (url example ".com/blog/") this function obviously runs as well.

So my question is how can I control the document.referrer function so that it will only return true for url's with characters after the last trailing slash? E.g. only for URL's that have .com/blog/blog-post and not for the base page .com/blog?

I am fairly new to Jquery and JavaScript, so searching online I have not found many questions around this specifically - as such your time and assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround to solving this entailed not using 'blog' for both the blog page and the blog categories. The Blog category now has a different url slug which resolved this issue (i.e. Blogs).